# <nav> size increases in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, less

I'm building a navigation bar, but there's one problem: its size appears to increase in Mozilla's Firefox browser:

[image: FF]

This is the expected size, controlled by a padding inside each column:

[image: Chrome|Opera]
(Opera)

What I've tried to avoid this was setting the navigation bar's magin and padding to 0, but nothing changed! What's wrong? I'm using the `<nav>` element for that (tried using `<div>`, too).

Before I post the snippet, I'll show a part of the LESS code (very similiar to CSS), where I stylize the navigation bar (menu):

```
#menu {
    background: @dark-next-menu-bg;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu .col {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    &:hover {
        background: #1c1c1c;
        color: #fff;
    }
}

#menu .col span {
    color: @dark-next-menu-text-color;
}
```

Here's the snippet with compiled CSS for testing:

```css
body,
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
body {
    margin: 0
}
.let-select {
    -webkit-user-select: initial;
    -moz-user-select: initial;
    -ms-user-select: initial;
    -o-user-select: initial;
    user-select: initial
}
.Dark-Next,
.no-select {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}
.Dark-Next {
    background: #444
}
.Dark-Next h1,
.Dark-Next h2,
.Dark-Next span {
    color: #fee;
    font-family: 'Segoe Ui', sans-serif
}
.Dark-Next h1 {
    font-size: 24px
}
.Dark-Next h1,
.Dark-Next h2 {
    font-weight: 200
}
.Dark-Next span {
    font-size: 12px
}
.Dark-Next button,
.Dark-Next input,
.Dark-Next select {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Segoe Ui', sans-serif;
    outline: 0
}
.Dark-Next button:focus,
.Dark-Next input:focus,
.Dark-Next select:focus {
    border-color: #48f
}
.Dark-Next select {
    background: #222;
    border: 1px solid #333
}
.Dark-Next select option {
    padding: 8px;
    background: #444!important
}
.Dark-Next #menu {
    background: #111;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.Dark-Next #menu .col {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 15px
}
.Dark-Next #menu .col:hover {
    background: #1c1c1c;
    color: #fff
}
.Dark-Next #menu .col span {
    color: #ccc
}
#menu {
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    position: relative
}
#menu .col {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 8px 14px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Map Editor Next</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>
<body class="Dark-Next">
    <nav id="menu">
        <div class="col">
            <span><i>NEXT</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>Map</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>Edit</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>View</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>Tools</span>
        </div>
        <select class="col">
            <option value="brush">Brush</option>
            <option value="eraser">Eraser</option>
        </select>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's your `<select>` that's expanding the nav, I believe. Perhaps try setting a smaller height, or even `height: 100%;`

Comment: @Santi Good idea, I've not thought on that

Comment: Have you considered line-height?

Comment: @Nick_O I didn't, but thanks for reminding, I'll update it too. Although what Santi commented solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See snippet (I added an `id` to select tag and style)

```css
body,
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
body {
    margin: 0
}
.let-select {
    -webkit-user-select: initial;
    -moz-user-select: initial;
    -ms-user-select: initial;
    -o-user-select: initial;
    user-select: initial
}
.Dark-Next,
.no-select {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}
.Dark-Next {
    background: #444
}
.Dark-Next h1,
.Dark-Next h2,
.Dark-Next span {
    color: #fee;
    font-family: 'Segoe Ui', sans-serif
}
.Dark-Next h1 {
    font-size: 24px
}
.Dark-Next h1,
.Dark-Next h2 {
    font-weight: 200
}
.Dark-Next span {
    font-size: 12px
}
.Dark-Next button,
.Dark-Next input,
.Dark-Next select {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Segoe Ui', sans-serif;
    outline: 0
}
.Dark-Next button:focus,
.Dark-Next input:focus,
.Dark-Next select:focus {
    border-color: #48f
}
.Dark-Next select {
    background: #222;
    border: 1px solid #333
}
.Dark-Next select option {
    padding: 8px;
    background: #444!important
}
.Dark-Next #menu {
    background: #111;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.Dark-Next #menu .col {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 15px
}
.Dark-Next #menu .col:hover {
    background: #1c1c1c;
    color: #fff
}
.Dark-Next #menu .col span {
    color: #ccc
}
#menu {
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    position: relative
}
#menu .col {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 8px 14px
}
#sel,#sel >*{
padding:0px !important  ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Map Editor Next</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>
<body class="Dark-Next">
    <nav id="menu">
        <div class="col">
            <span><i>NEXT</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>Map</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>Edit</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>View</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>Tools</span>
        </div>
        <select class="col" id="sel">
            <option value="brush">Brush</option>
            <option value="eraser">Eraser</option>
        </select>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah! So the Firefox adds padding to select, I prefered this solution rather than re-setting height as commented in the question

Comment: yea..standard implementation for select tag

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ to your project which is fairly standard?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, maybe I can use this helper in future projects !